# Tradingview’s Pine: saving var between bar

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Saving variable value between bars for future use shall be possible by using `var` during a variable’s declaration. In the case at hand the highest identified bar value shall be saved and updated if an even higher one is fetched.

```
var float topp = 0
float curr = high
if curr > topp
    topp := curr
```

The idea is that *when the script is started,* the highest value is at 0 and gets updated incrementally while the script is running and a new high is found. However, the code immediately fetches some much higher value many bars back and keeps it. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pinescript, when a script start, it begins to loop from a lot of bars back (I think approximatly 20 000).
Those bars are called historical bars.
Then the script deal with your real time bar.

If your want your script only deal with the real time bar (the last one one the right on your chart), you should add a condition so that it execute only on real time bar :
var float

```
topp = 0
if barstate.isrealtime
    float curr = high
    if curr > topp
        topp := curr
```

This way your script will execute only from the real time bar since you activate it.